# Релевентный поиск с помощья mysgl-запроса. Строковые функции mysql, посчитать совпадения искомого в поле таблицы (текстовый поиск в таблице)

Tags: mysql, строки, функции, поиск, подстрока

*Расшифровываю заголовок сего сообщения:*

У меня уже есть и отлично работает поиск (и в постах и в комментах). Релевантный поиск в постах тоже реализован и работает, но реализовано оно через одно место. При выводе результатов обычного поиска в постах, по умолчанию посты выводятся от новый к старым. Возможность сортировки пользователем имеется. В самом запросе они сортируются по `pid` - PostId.

Поиск в ПОЛЕ таблицы постов осуществляется по такому шаблончику **SS, %SS, SS%/, %SS%**.

SS - это строка для поиска.

Вот запрос (на самом деле он более сложный. в таблице есть параметры доступа к посту и всякие джоины, но это к теме не относится. Зачем перегружать излишками):

```
    $q = "select pid,title_posts,txt_posts,postpic_posts from posts where 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?)
                order by pid $asc_desc limit ? offset ?";
```

Вместо *lower(txt_posts) like lower(**?**)* и подставляются (привязываются) **SS, %SS, SS%/, %SS%**.

Сортировка по **pid** - выше уже упоминал об этом. **Что хочу?**: Хочу чтобы в результате запроса к
`pid, title_posts, txt_posts, postpic_posts` добавилось поле с количеством совпадений искомого. Нужно, например, получить такие результаты
`count_relev_ss, pid, title_posts, txt_posts, postpic_posts`.

Ранее (когда он был бело-зеленый) на https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ было понятнее что где искать. А сейчас не вполне понятно. Да и простого ответа на мой вопрос там нет.

`count_relev_ss` нужен для сортировки по релевантности. Только как его посчитать?

Например:

```
    $q = "select pid,title_posts,txt_posts,postpic_posts from posts where 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) or 
                lower(txt_posts) like lower(?)
                order by count_relev_ss $asc_desc limit ? offset ?";
```

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Comment: *Вместо lower(txt_posts) like lower(?) и подставляются (привязываются) SS, %SS, SS%/, %SS%.* Бессмысленно - всё, что соответствует первым трём шаблонам, соответствует и последнему, так что одного `%SS%` вполне достаточно. И использование `LOWER()` только тормозит процесс, достаточно установить регистронезависимый COLLATION, чтобы использование функции стало ненужным.

Comment: @Akina, НЕТ, не соответствует .

Comment: Да ладно! приведите пример значения и искомой подстроки, которая находится по одному из первых трёх шаблонов, но не находится по четвёртому...

Comment: @Akina, по поводу lower() - знаю, но пока что так.

Comment: И поясните, что разумеется под "поле с количеством совпадений искомого". Это что, сколько раз подстрока поиска содержится в тестируемом значении, что ли?

Comment: @Akina, сколько раз искомое содержится в поле тбл, в котором идёт поиск.

Comment: А перекрытия - считаются? сколько раз "аба" содержится в "абаба" - один или два?

Comment: по поводу перекрытий не в курсе, наверное нет.

Comment: Нет - это один или два?

Comment: могу видео снять и наглядно показать - это я по поводу SS. Я спенциально класс для этого создал (чтобы присоединять % к поисковой строке справа слева и с обеих сторон).  Если в поле тбл есть только "слово", а ШАБЛОН для поиска = "%слово%" ИЛИ "%слово" ИЛИ "слово%", то совпадения НЕ БУДЕТ. Я сам был в шоке от этого.

Comment: @Akina , перекрытия не должны учитываться

Comment: @Mike, интересно. Нужно обязательно протестировать.

Comment: *Я сам был в шоке от этого.* Ну-ну... небось с кодировками накосячено. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30d7967f6ce7a415cbbf24b699b12d8d - попробуй опровергнуть. *перекрытия не должны учитываться* Неужели так трудно выбрать одно слово из двух? Скажи или "один", или "два"...

Comment: ОДИН раз
.,,,,,,

Comment: Тогда `occurences = (LENGTH(word) - LENGTH(REPLACE(word, pattern, ''))) / LENGTH(pattern)`

Comment: @Akina, по поводу "с кордировками накосячил" -  у мене один запрос, у вас другой. 

Всем спасибо. буду пробовать теститировать...